# On duplicate key update issue

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to update field on duplicate key, but it just adds new records instead of updating.

Here is what i'm trying to do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "insert into open_offer_counters (offer_id, udid, open_counter) values #{opened_events.join(", ")} on duplicate key update open_counter = open_counter + 1"
```

In my migration I pointed on 2 unique fields

```
create_table :open_offer_counters do |t|
    t.integer :offer_id,            :unique => true
    t.string  :udid,                :unique => true
    t.integer :open_counter
  t.timestamps
end
```

Any ideas whats wrong with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique index on these columns, such as

```
add_index :open_offer_counters, :offer_id, :unique => true
```

Passing :unique as a column option doesn't do anything

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. Made new migration and drop\create\seed db

Answer (score 0):

in your above script you ar eupdating the open_counter=open_counter+1 and hence this will become unique and add new row.Instead do like this.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "insert into open_offer_counters (offer_id, udid, open_counter) values #{opened_events.join(", ")} on duplicate key update open_counter = open_counter,offer_id=offer_id, udid=udid"
```